# On Windows/mingw, what is the equivalent of `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_ACCMODE`?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, file-descriptor

I am compiling a program on Windows with Mingw. How can I get the access mode for an open file descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Win32.hlp, the API supplies the function `BOOL GetFileInformationByHandle(HANDLE hFile, LPBY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation)` in KERNEL32.  `LPBY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION` is a `BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION*`, where `BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION` is as follows:

```
typedef struct _BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION { // bhfi  
    DWORD    dwFileAttributes; 
    FILETIME ftCreationTime; 
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime; 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime; 
    DWORD    dwVolumeSerialNumber; 
    DWORD    nFileSizeHigh; 
    DWORD    nFileSizeLow; 
    DWORD    nNumberOfLinks; 
    DWORD    nFileIndexHigh; 
    DWORD    nFileIndexLow; 
} BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION;
```

After calling said function, if it returns true, the `BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION` contains data pertinent to your file.  `dwFileAttributes` may contain the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY` flag.

If you want more than that, there is also:

```
BOOL GetKernelObjectSecurity(
 HANDLE Handle,                             // handle of object to query
 SECURITY_INFORMATION RequestedInformation, // requested information
 PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor,  // address of security descriptor
 DWORD nLength,                             // size of buffer for security descriptor 
 LPDWORD lpnLengthNeeded                    // address of required size of buffer
);
```

The API reference is necessarily vague on what a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` is, but you can call a bunch of other functions using its address as a parameter to get specific properties.  The `SECURITY_INFORMATION` is just a `DWORD` constant specifying which of these functions you plan to call.  You can find more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446641%28VS.85%29.aspx

Edit - the second code section keeps coming out looking screwy, but the link to the API reference will lead you where you need to go if you dig around a bit.

Comment: This answer is not answering what the asker was asking. `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY` tells you whether the file is marked as read-only, not whether the handle you have to it is for read/write/both. (You can have a read-only handle to a read-write file.) And `GetKernelObjectSecurity` gives you the ACLs of the underlying object, which also doesn't tell you about the access rights of a specific handle to it. I haven't tested it myself, but I believe the correct answer was actually given on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082758/2147204

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you cant.

https://web.archive.org/web/20161107234935/http://www.zemris.fer.hr/predmeti/os1/misc/Unix2Win.htm is a good guide for unix-to-windows porting.

Maybe you could use the Cygwin POSIX "emulation"?