# C File Operations: Check opened file pointer access mode

Tags: c

A simple question:

How do I check the access mode of an already opened file pointer?

So say a function is passed an already opened FILE pointer:

```
    //Pseudo code
    bool PseudoFunction(FILE *Ptr)
    {
        if( ... Insert check for read-only access rights )
        {
            //It's read only access mode
            return true;
        }
       //File pointer is not read-only and thus write operations are permitted
       return false;
    }
```

What would I use in the if statement to check the FILE pointer had been opened as read-only (or not, as the case may be), without writing to the file, and without relying on the user passing (possibly contradicting) arguments?

System is windows, code::blocks compiler, but for interests of code portability, cross-compatibility preferred.

Note, this isn't asking about file rights, but what access mode has been used by FILE pointer.

**SELF-ANSWER** [Cannot append a separate answer due to user rights limitations]:

**There is a better answer by another poster below that includes the proper #defines**

As earlier suggested, it appears the FILE pointer's _flag (as defined under _iobuf) is the key for knowing whether or not a file is read only. Your mileage may vary though, but the same basic concept should be easily adaptable, example code:

```
#define READ_ONLY_FLAG 1

bool PrintFlagPtr(const char FileName[], const char AccessMode[])
{
    FILE *Ptr = NULL;
    Ptr = fopen(FileName,AccessMode);
    printf("%s: %d ",AccessMode,Ptr->_flag);

    int IsReadOnly = Ptr->_flag;
    fclose(Ptr);
    Ptr = NULL;


    if( (IsReadOnly&READ_ONLY_FLAG) == READ_ONLY_FLAG )
    {
        printf("File is read only!\n");
        return true;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return false;
}
```

That, when all the different access mode combinations are used with above function, produces an output of:

```
Output:
w: 2
r: 1 File is read only!
a: 2
wb: 2
rb: 1 File is read only!
ab: 2
w+: 128
r+: 128
a+: 128
w+b: 128
r+b: 128
a+b: 128
```

I am curious as to why this was never suggested (or never used), given a cross-compatible front-end function (simply a function with the same name, with declarations depending on platform) passing a const int sourced from the given FILE pointer _flag would be quite a simple and easy solution to the problem.

Comment: Avoid using an oracle to discover something that's readily known within your program.  Some code created the FILE, that code also knows *how* it was created.  Add an argument to your function.

Comment: Actually, relying on the user to tell us what access rights a file has is bad form (as stated) given this is a security vulnerability. And this is programming, not predictions - part of the code already knows what the access rights are in order to be able to error when using putc and similar commands.

Comment: No idea why you think the user has anything to do with this.  It requires a C programmer to pass arguments to a function.  If you don't trust the programmer then all bets are off.

Comment: Although this is C, in the expanded language of C++, private and protected are used by classes to protect variables, which again, only the programmers can access and not the users - so obviously the practice is perfectly valid (especially if you want a straight-forward front-end you can just use and not have to 'learn'). It's generally good practice not to assume _anything_ (because assumptions lead quite often to bugs)... [continued]

Comment: ...and there is easily the possibility of a programmer passing a FILE pointer that is read only, but passing the conflicting argument it's writable, which is a security flaw and obviously a bug. Best way to avoid bugs is not to let them crop up in the first place. Besides, the whole point of the above function, is to detect a FILE pointer's access mode (which if was already known defeats the point) in order to avoid bugs. Prevention is better than the cure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: this answer is specific to Visual Studio 2010.

---

The stdio.h file that comes with Visual Studio 2010 defines the FILE type like this:

```
struct _iobuf {
    char *_ptr;
    int   _cnt;
    char *_base;
    int   _flag;
    int   _file;
    int   _charbuf;
    int   _bufsiz;
    char *_tmpfname;
};
typedef struct _iobuf FILE;
```

When fopening a file with the "rb" mode, it gets the value of 0x00000001.

In the fopen function, some of the flags you're interesed in can be mapped as this:

```
r    _IOREAD
w    _IOWRT
a    _IOWRT
+    _IORW
```

These constants are defined in stdio.h:

```
#define _IOREAD         0x0001
#define _IOWRT          0x0002
#define _IORW           0x0080
```

The underlying file descriptor contains more info, I haven't dug further yet.

Comment: As your answer contains more information than my answer (I couldn't find the #defines in code::blocks [works for code::blocks too], but similar context), I will select yours. I'd only add the suggestion of a front-end function that accesses _file is used so on different operating systems the function can be re-defined to suit. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

**On Linux (and possibly all UNIX systems)** you could use `fcntl` to get the access mode of the file:

```
int get_file_status(FILE* f) {
    int fd = fileno(f);
    return fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
}
```

Note that the returned value is an integer as combination of flags like `O_RDONLY` or `O_RDWR`, not the `"r"` or `"w+"` strings. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/open.html for some  of these flags.

Not sure about Windows, see [On Windows/mingw, what is the equivalent of `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_ACCMODE`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636875/on-windows-mingw-what-is-the-equivalent-of-fcntlfd-f-getfl-o-accmode).

Comment: The question you've linked to for windows, appears to be 7 months old and has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to achieve that.

Comment: What about accessing _flag under the FILE pointer? Surely this contains the read/write attributes as int flags and one merely has to compare it to any pre-defined numbers to find out? Whilst I am sure this might be frowned upon, I don't see why not so long as _flag is treated as a const and dealt with under the covers (and certainly better than perhaps awkward work arounds?). It seems odd that the program can know a FILE pointer is read only (and thus will refuse to write) but I as the programmer can't.

Comment: FILE is opaque, you don't know which members it has.

Comment: Merely writing class FILE{}; and forcing the compiler to complain about a previously declared instance of FILE reveals what members it has. Being a well defined _iobuf class, one can always look it up online if necessary.

Comment: You are asking for portable code, I inform you that there is no way to achieve this while staying conformant to ISO 9899. You can look at different scope standards (like POSIX as Kenny did, but I'd not give a POSIX answer to someone whose main target is Windows if I don't know beforehand that Windows support it) and at informal one (but I know of none for this). Documented interface for your platform fails short of "portable" to me, without speaking about non documented one.

Comment: If you refer to code::blocks, it does indeed also run on linux. Using #defines and detecting platform one could build a helper function front-end (which is implemented to access the equal to _flag on the various systems). However, preferably portable is noted (it's not an outright requirement) - this is to minimise any changes to the code if ported.