# How to get FILE pointer "fopened" mode from a function parameter?

Tags: c, stdio

I have function

```
bool disk_read_address(struct Node *y, uint64_t address, FILE *file)
{
//...
}
```

How can I check whether is file mode "rb" or not in functions definition ?
(same question with "r+b" and "wb")

Comment: `fstat` and `fileno` if using POSIX?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such function. You may have to manually check that no caller passes an "invalid" FILE. Or, you might want to build an abstraction on top of, or replacing, the standard FILE which has all the additional information you need.

Comment: @smac89 "Warning: this answer is specific to Visual Studio 2010.". I use GNU/Linux

Comment: The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026008/2089675) on that page addresses Linux

Comment: @smac89 do you suggest write something like `if (fcntl(\*...*\) == 32770)` ?

Comment: It should work, yes. But you'd better keep the fcntl.h constants rather than putting an hardcoded integer value...