# How to get access rights on an open win32 HANDLE

Tags: windows

When you call `CreateFile`, you pass in `dwDesiredAccess` to determine if the handle should be writeable/readable/deleteable/etc.

If I'm passed an open handle, how do I recover these access rights? Specifically, I'm interested in whether the handle is writeable (... without actually writing to the handle).

Even *more* specifically, I'm getting 'access denied' errors on FlushFileBuffers(), and I'm guessing it's because they weren't opened with `GENERIC_WRITE`, would like to ignore those errors if that's the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this exist function [`NtQueryObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383(v=vs.85).aspx) with `ObjectBasicInformation` *ObjectInformationClass*

```
    OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION obi;
    if (0 <= NtQueryObject(h, ObjectBasicInformation, &obi, sizeof(obi),0))
    {
        // use obi.GrantedAccess;
    }
```